# How to cite Rascal in a paper?

Tags: rascal

I'm writing a paper and want to cite Rascal. Which is the preferred paper I should cite? Or should I just cite a link to the website? There are no publications mentioned on the website. The Wikipedia entry mentions a publication from 2013 (13th SCAM). Shall I use this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rascal repository has a [CITATION.md](https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/blob/master/CITATION.md). The SCAM2009 is a common citation indeed.

To quote it:

#### General Language Reference

You {c,sh,w}ould cite this if:

- you extended Rascal itself and publish about this
- you used Rascal as a component of your research method
- you used Rascal to implement an industrial software project and you wish to credit it

```
@inproceedings{RascalGTTSE,
    title = {EASY Meta-Programming with Rascal. Leveraging the Extract-Analyze-SYnthesize Paradigm for Meta-Programming},
    author = {Paul  Klint and Tijs van der Storm and Jurgen J.  Vinju},
    year = {2010},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 3rd International Summer School on Generative and Transformational Techniques in Software Engineering (GTTSE'09)},
    location = {Braga, Portugal},
    series = {LNCS},
    publisher = {Springer},
}
```

#### Software Analysis and Transformation (Refactoring)

You {c,sh,w}ould cite this if:

- you are working on related work want to position w.r.t. Rascal's features
- you used Rascal as a component of your own tool

```
@inproceedings{rascal,
      Author = {Paul Klint and Tijs van der Storm and Jurgen J. Vinju},
      Title = {RASCAL: A Domain Specific Language for Source Code Analysis and Manipulation},
      Booktitle = {Ninth IEEE International Working Conference on Source Code Analysis and Manipulation (SCAM)},
      Doi = {http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/SCAM.2009.28},
      Pages = {168-177},
      Publisher = {IEEE Computer Society},
      Year = {2009},
}
```

Comment: This is a total minor thing, but isn't the SCAM2009 paper the second paper?